# How to run mysqldump on a Heroku app

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

I want to make daily dumps of my production database that I can store in S3.  I have created a bash script that works fine locally, but when run on Heroku's postinstall, I get the following error message:

`./run-backup.sh: line 21: mysqldump: command not found`

as it tries to run the following line:

`mysqldump -u $CLEARDB_USER_NAME -h $CLEARDB_SERVER_IP -p$CLEARDB_PASSWORD --databases $DATABASE | gzip -c > "/tmp/db-backups/$BACKUP_FILE_NAME.gz"`

So the script works fine, but Heroku can't run it. I am not sure where to go from here?

Here is the script in full:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Beginning database backup"

#install aws-cli
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip -o awscli-bundle.zip
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
chmod +x ./awscli-bundle/install
./awscli-bundle/install -i /tmp/aws

# new backup file name
BACKUP_FILE_NAME="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")-$APP-$DATABASE.sql"

# if directory '/tmp/db-backups' doesn't exist, create it
if [ ! -d "/tmp/db-backups" ]; then
  mkdir -p /tmp/db-backups/
fi

# dump the current DB into /tmp/db-backups/<new-file-name>
mysqldump -u $CLEARDB_USER_NAME -h $CLEARDB_SERVER_IP -p$CLEARDB_PASSWORD --databases $DATABASE | gzip -c > "/tmp/db-backups/$BACKUP_FILE_NAME.gz"

# using the aws cli, copy the new backup to our s3 bucket
/tmp/aws/bin/aws s3 cp /tmp/db-backups/$BACKUP_FILE_NAME.gz s3://$S3_BUCKET_PATH/$DATABASE/$BACKUP_FILE_NAME.gz --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

echo "backup $BACKUP_FILE_NAME.gz complete"
```

Comment: heroku does not have `mysqldump` program so it can't execute this script

Comment: Try to use buildpack https://github.com/Shopify/heroku-buildpack-mysql, first you have to install it `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/gaumire/heroku-buildpack-mysql`

Comment: Thanks a lot @djsmentya that was exactly what I wanted